# Cron Job with Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, cron, command

I'm trying to find out **how to set up a cron job in Laravel 4**, and the command I would need to run in artisan for it.

In Laravel 3, there were `Tasks` but these don't seem to be there anymore and there is no documentation as to how to do it...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Tasks have been replaced with [commands](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/commands#building-a-command), which are the same thing in Laravel 4, but integrated with Symfony's console component, and even more powerful than before.

Comment: I found this article helpful too. Shows how exactly to call the "command" in crontab: http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/practical-laravel-using-cron-jobs-in-laravel/

Answer (score 37):

Below I detail a tutorial for using `commands` in `Laravel 4` with cron. I have divided into four steps to make it easier to follow.

---

### STEP #1: Create a command in Laravel 4:

```
php artisan command:make RefreshStats
```

With command above, Laravel will create a file named `RefreshStats.php` in directory  `app/commands/`

**RefreshStats.php** it's a file like this:

```
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;

class RefreshStats extends Command {

        protected $name = 'command:name';
        protected $description = 'Command description.';

        public function __construct() {
                parent::__construct();
        }

        public function fire(){

        }

        protected function getArguments() {
            return array(
                array('example', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'An example argument.'),
            );
        }

        protected function getOptions() {
            return array(
                array('example', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'An example option.', null),
            );
        }

}
```

---

### STEP #2: Simple "*configuration*" of RefreshStats file:

You should change this line:

```
protected $name = 'command:name';
```

to something like this:

```
protected $name = 'refresh:stats';
```

If you don't need arguments (*same for options*), change this line:

```
protected function getArguments() {
      return array(
          array('example', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'An example argument.'),
      );
}
```

to:

```
protected function getArguments() {
      return array();
}
```

And now **pay attention** to the `fire` function. The command will execute source code that is wrote in that function. Example:

```
public function fire(){
    echo "Hello world";    
}
```

---

### STEP #3: Register the command:

You need to register the command. So open `app/start/artisan.php` file, and add one line as below:

```
Artisan::add(new RefreshStats);
```

---

### STEP #4: Create *CRON* scheduled task:

Finally, you can add a scheduled task as follow:

```
crontab -e
```

And add a line (*run command every 30 minutes*) like below:

```
*/30 * * * * php path_laravel_project/artisan refresh:stats
```

---

### And all will work **automagically**!

Comment: Very nice explanation

Comment: @tomloprod how to check that cron is working or not ? you write echo "Hello world"; in fire() function but where it will print "Hello world" .
I know its basic but i am new to php.

Comment: @AdarshTiwari It's a simple example. This will print `Hello world` in console. Instead of `echo "Hello world"` you have to write your code. For example, send a mail: `mail("foo@bar.es", "Subject", "Hello world", "From:fromemail@foo.es");`

Comment: @tomloprod, could you please explain where should I write `crontab -e` and `*/30 * * * * php path_laravel_project/artisan refresh:stats` ?

Comment: @vijayrana Depends of your development environment. Where are you trying to use commands?

Comment: I am using laravel 4.2 and testing on local host. I followed up to step #3. and stucked. Sorry to bother :)

Comment: I have explained myself wrong, hehe. Are you on Windows, Linux, ...?

Comment: Yes, I am on windows. I tried to run `crontab -e` but got this `sh: crontab: command not found`

Comment: On Windows there is no cron .... you need to use the scheduler task from Windows to create a "Cronjob". See this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721931.aspx and then keep going the #4 step :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129208/discussion-between-vijayrana-and-tomloprod).

Comment: If the name of the class/command is "RefreshStats," why is the crontab running "refresh:stats?"  Those aren't the same thing.

Comment: @AndrewKoper `refresh:stats` is the value of the `$name` protected attribute. In crontab you must use this value. However, you can set `Refresh:Stats` to `$name` and use this in crontab.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative, if you don't like commands there is an unofficial Laravel 4 cron package: https://github.com/liebig/cron

Answer (score 0):

OK so I found [this](https://gist.github.com/sisou/889971461616661d2ed6) useful for setting up crons in laravel 4.2.