# Error when trying to run cron [There are no commands defined in the "cron" namespace]

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, laravel-4, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I am using Laravel 4.2 and I am trying to run a cronjob.
I followed up [that link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520955/cron-job-with-laravel-4) to implement a cronjob in my project.

The cronjob is working fine one my local machine (Ubuntu). I do not know why but not on my server when I use the following command:

```
sudo php artisan cron:run
```

Then I am getting the red colored error in terminal

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>    There are no commands defined in the "cron" namespace

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Quick thought: do you have cPanel? It's cronJob feature works like a charm

Comment: hey Adrenaxus..just fixed the issue..there was some code error in laraval..we need to register a cron before running it..BTW thanks for response :)

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it! Please answer your own question for any future users who encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just look for the file

app/start/artisan.php

and after that you have to put code in that file like

```
Artisan::add(new CronRunCommand);
```

CronRunCommand is the name of the  file created in the app/commands folder.

That is most relevant solution for above problem.

Comment: Same problem but in Magento 2.1 there is no app/start -folder anymore.