# cron job for laravel 4 won't work

Tags: php, laravel-4, cron

I am following this [Cron Job with Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520955/cron-job-with-laravel-4) as tutorial for cron in laravel 4 but it seems it's not working. This is my `/app/commands/ReleaseOptionBooking.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;

class ReleaseOptionBooking extends Command {

    /**
     * The console command name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name = 'release:option';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Check booking expirations';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function fire()
    {
        $to = "bikegearup@gmail.com";
        $subject = "My subject";
        $txt = "Hello world!";
        $headers = "From: admin@theskitrip.ca" . "\r\n";

        mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
    }

    /**
     * Get the console command arguments.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getArguments()
    {
        return array(
            array('example', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'An example argument.'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the console command options.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        return array(
            array('example', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'An example option.', null),
        );
    }

}
```

and this is on `/app/start/artisan.php`

`Artisan::add(new ReleaseOptionBooking);`

and on my server's `crontab -e`

`*/10 * * * * php /var/www/myproject/protected/artisan release:option`

do anyone have an idea about my case?

I got this error:

```
  [RuntimeException]
  Not enough arguments.



release:option [--example[="..."]] example
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have ssh access to your server?
Could you try to execute command manually:

```
php /var/www/myproject/protected/artisan release:option
```

Do you see any error messages? Any output?

Comment: so cron job is running normally. Solve problem with your code. Remove required argument check from protected function getArguments()

Answer (score 0):

Remove these examples from your command code:

```
/**
 * Get the console command arguments.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getArguments()
{
    return array(
        array('example', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'An example argument.'),
    );
}

/**
 * Get the console command options.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getOptions()
{
    return array(
        array('example', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'An example option.', null),
    );
}
```