# laravel 4.1.28 command registration is not working

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently working with Laravel version 4.1.28 and have created a command with **php artisan command:make** which works fine and created a file under **app/commands/ArchiveMailorder.php**:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;

class ArchiveMailorder extends Command {

    protected $name = 'archive:mailorder';

    protected $description = 'This is my first command';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function fire()
    {
      $this->line("Hello world");
    }

    protected function getArguments()
    {
        return array(
            array(),
        );
    }

    protected function getOptions()
    {
        return array(
            array(),
        );
    }
}
```

Now when I try to register this command inside **app/start/artisan.php** like:

```
    Artisan::add(new ArchiveMailorder());
Or
\Illuminate\Foundation\Artisan::add(new ArchiveMailorder());
Or
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::add(new ArchiveMailorder());
```

I get the following error:

```
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Missing argument 1 for Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command::addArgument()","file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\mocs\\vendor\\symfony\\console\\Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command.php","line":362}}
```

I have followed these links for creating and registering a command:

[Cron Job with Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520955/cron-job-with-laravel-4/31560112)

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/commands#building-a-command

But still can not make the command work. So please tell me what am I doing wrong? And what shall I do to fix this problem?

Oh, and comoser.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
        "mews/purifier": "dev-master",
        "anahkiasen/former": "dev-master",
        "laracasts/utilities": "1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In laravel 4.1/4.2  you register command simple just by adding

`Artisan::add(new SomeCommandName());`

In your command your issue lies with this function:

```
  protected function getArguments()
    {
        return array(
            array(),
        );
    }
```

Remove that function unless you're supplying arguments. Since you're returning an array.

Unless you need any of these functions, you'll just need these two functions to get you started, consult the laravel docs for anything else I guess? :

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function fire()
{
  // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: You are right. I am getting that error due to passing empty arrays. It was so simple to determine. But thanks a lot for your input.

Comment: No worries @Capri82, you can find more information [here](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/commands#building-a-command) which I know is the link you posted but it explains it under the **Arguments & Options** section which of course allow you to add things like `php artisan archive:mailorder <arg1> <arg2> --<option>`

Comment: For example: let's say Unix `rm` command. `rm <options>` would be `rm -rf` which in this case gives us the recursive/force flags. Then the argument would be the directory such as `rm -rf ~/some/Dir/To/Remove` hope this explanation helps, happy coding.